# iphone: error while integrating Zxing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I get the following error while integrating ZXing in the iphone app.

For Line:

```
#import <zxing/common/Counted.h>
```

I get error:

```
error: zxing/common/Counted.h: No such file or directory
```

what could be wrong?

How can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Xcode cannot find the file. Where did you save the zxing folder?
You may change it to `#import "zxing/common/Counted.h"`
And add the path to the Header Search Path in your Build settings.

EDIT:
Counted.h does not exist in the objc src folder.
It only exists in the symbian and in the cpp folder.
You do not use the correct sources.

Comment: Counted.h does not exist in the objc src folder. It only exists in the symbian and in the cpp folder. You do not use the correct sources.

Comment: Counted.h IS in zxing/common/Counted.h. I have the same problem and I have checked that. And this import is FROM THE LIBRARY, not some custom code written by the user of the library.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "ZXingWidgetController.h"
#import "QRCodeReader.h"
```

should be used instead-although they give me file no found too...